# FFTW linking with g++ error on windows machine

Tags: c++, g++, fftw, linkage

I am trying to learn to use FFTW on a windows machine compiling using g++ from windows command line. I have read the FFTW manual and search the forums but nothing seems to be the same as my issue. I think I am not understanding how to link to the FFTW library properly. I have downloaded the FFTW3.zip file and copied all the files into the directory that my .cpp file is in. My simple example is to transform a sin wave with the code provided:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<studio.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<fftw3.h>



int main(){
        int length = 1000;
        fftw_complex time[length];
        fftw_complex signal[length];
        fftw_complex fftsignal[length];
        double omega = 1;
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
            time[i][0] = 0.1*i;
            time[i][1] = 0;
            signal[i][0] = sin(time[i][0]*omega);
            signal[i][1] = 0;
        }

        ofstream savefile;
        string name = "sinwave.txt";
        savefile.open(name);
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
            savefile <<time[i][0]<<"\t"<<signal[i][0]<<endl;
        }
        savefile.close();

        fftw_plan my_plan;

        my_plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(length,signal,fftsignal,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

        fftw_execute(my_plan);
        fftw_destroy_plan(my_plan);
        fftw_free(signal);
        fftw_free(fftsignal);
    }
```

The command I use to compile is:

```
g++ -I..filepath..\\"FFTW learning" -L..filepath..\\"FFTW learning" -std=c++11 FFTW.cpp -Lfftw3 -lm
```

The error gives me multiple underfined references to various objects that I cannot locate in the fftw3 file or my own. It futher states that "the final link failed" in the last line of the error.

```
C:\Users\1915821\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnK99CJ.o:FFTW.cpp:(.text+0x1408): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_plan_dft_1d'
C:\Users\1915821\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnK99CJ.o:FFTW.cpp:(.text+0x1422): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_execute'
C:\Users\1915821\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnK99CJ.o:FFTW.cpp:(.text+0x1435): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_destroy_plan'
C:\Users\1915821\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnK99CJ.o:FFTW.cpp:(.text+0x1448): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_free'
C:\Users\1915821\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnK99CJ.o:FFTW.cpp:(.text+0x145b): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_free'
c:/programs/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\1915821\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnK99CJ.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
c:/programs/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have also tried using all combinations of upper and lowercase -l for links, all return the error

```
cannot find -lfftw3
```

If anyone knows how to link properly to these libraries or can spot why my linking does not work I appreciate the help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the contents of `..filepath..\\"FFTW learning"` so we can help you construct the proper command line.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am on a server system at my university so the filepath is a little odd but it goes as: \\tawe_dfs\students\1\1915821\Desktop\\"C++ Programs"\\"FFTW learning"

Comment: I also realize that I forgot to include -std=c++11 before the FFTW.cpp command in the above compile command.

Comment: By contents I meant "what files are there".

Comment: Right, of course. Here's a link to a screenshot of the folder contents. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUxS5.png

Comment: so `-llibfftw3-3` ?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I have tried using -llibfftw3-3 for which I get the error "cannont find -llibfftw3-3" and -Llibfftw3-3 for which I get the original error listed saying that there are undefind references and that the final link has failed.

Comment: `-L` tells the linker WHERE to search. `-l` tells the linker WHAT to link in. So you should add `-L..filepath..\\"FFTW learning" -lllibfftw3-3` You can also just use `-L.` to point to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help Botje, I just stumbled upon that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaking my linking directory command with the library name command. The correct g++ command comes in as:

```
g++ -I\\tawe_dfs\students\1\1915821\Desktop\\"C++ Programs"\\"FFTW learning" -L\\tawe_dfs\students\1\1915821\Desktop\\"C++ Programs"\\"FFTW learning" -std=c++11 FFTW.cpp -llibfftw3-3
```

This error highlights my ignorance as the -L command specifies a directory for the compiler while the -l command specifies a library name.

Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: See my remark about `-L.` above. `-I.` works similarly. If you go beyond a single .cpp file, consider writing a Makefile to tie it all together and spare your wrists.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is on Windows, I suspect fftw is offered as a .lib file. In which case, you cannot just use `-l` (only works for .a and .so files), you need to do `-llibfftw3`. It's a deviation from convention, but Mingw states the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried using -llibfftw3, -llibfftw3-3, -llibfftwl3-3, and -llibbfftwf3-3. all .dll files included in the .zip file. All these produce the same error. There are no .lib files in the .zip provided by FFTW.